# What are the perks in Call of Duty: Ghosts?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

Call of Duty: Ghosts has a pretty similar game style to previous games in the series, but knowing what the perks are can be useful.

Comment: [this list](http://www.codghosts.net/perks-list/) seems a bit more informative that the one linked to in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Speed:**

Quickdraw – aim down sight faster

Sleight of Hand – reload faster

Agility – move faster

Marathon – sprint for longer

Stalker – move at faster while aiming down sights

**Handling:**

Strong Arm – throw grenades farther, decrease the cook time of grenades

On the Go – reload while sprinting

Reflex – switch between primary and secondary weapons quicker

Steady aim – increased hip-fire accuracy

Dexterity – weapons ready faster after sprinting

**Stealth:**

Takedown – killing enemies won’t reveal their death skull to team mates

Blind Eye - provides stealth against aggressive killstreaks

Off the Grid – immune to SAT-COM and radar pings

Dead Silence – make less/no noise

Ghost – no red name when targeted

**Awareness:**

Recon – spot enemies through explosives and hitmarkers

Scavenger – resupply

Sitrep – detect enemy equipment

Awareness – hear enemies easier

Wiretap - upgrades your SAT-COMs by hacking into active enemy SAT-COMs

**Resistance:**

Lightweight – no fall damage

Painkiller – faster health regeneration

Toughness – less flinch when shot

Tac Resist – resistance to flash, stun and EMP effects

Blast Shield – increased explosives resistance

**Equipment:**

Tac Reset – extra tactical grenade

Lethal +1 – extra lethal grenade

Fully Loaded – max ammo capacity

Three attachments on primary weapon

Danger Close – increased explosive damage

**Elite:**

Gambler – 1 random perk

Hardline – earn Killstreaks quicker

Ping – when you kill an enemy it will locate enemies near by the body

Overkill – choose two primary weapons

Deadeye – consecutive kills increase the chance to deal more damage with guns

Answer (score -3):

The full list of perks can be found here: http://geekfed.com/call-of-duty-ghosts-perk-list/628

**Speed:**

- Quickdraw
- Sleight of Hand
- Agility
- Marathon
- Stalker

**Handling:**

- Strong Arm
- On the Go
- Fast Hands
- Steady aim
- Dexterity

**Stealth:**

- Takedown
- Blind Eye
- Off the Grid
- Dead Silence
- Ghost

**Awareness:**

- Recon
- Scavenger
- Sitrep
- Awareness
- Wiretap

**Resistance:**

- Lightweight
- Painkiller
- Toughness
- Tac Resist
- Blast Shield

**Equipment:**

- Tac Reset
- Lethal +1
- Fully Loaded
- Three attachments on primary weapon (name not known)
- Danger Close

**Elite:**

- Gambler
- Hardline
- Ping
- Overkill
- Deadeye

Comment: Wouldn't it be more usefull to at least add wath every perk does, a name says nothing.

Comment: @Arperum He linked to a source that does.

Comment: @Dynamic I have multiple problems with his source: 1) it could die and then his answer is suddenly worthless, 2) it is to one of his own blogposts, so copy+paste wouldn't be too much work at all. 3)The only purpose of this post is generate more clicks on the other page so he gets more add revenue or something, which is not allowed by the FAQ.

Comment: @Arperum I see where you're coming from, and I agree. Although, he technically _is_ answering the question - the OP only asked for a list of perks not what they are.

Comment: @Dynamic The poster of this answer IS the OP, and knowing the name of a perk is not usefull *at all*, knowing what it does though, that's usefull. Mind taking this discussion to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge)?